# In C#, how do I unit-test client-side user interaction and javascript (jQuery) code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, unit-testing

I am new to unit-test.  My application is in ASP.NET with C#.  How do I both test javascript (jQuery with AJAX) code that are run on the client-side and user interaction like clicking on a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unit tests* are written in the same language as the system under test. They test individual units and not the integration between them; such tests would be *integration tests*.

As such, the ASP.NET, C# and JavaScript code will all be unit-tested using different frameworks.